# Generate value from Date in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python Pandas dataframe like below this with Date, that i have picked up from ExifTag from pictures files.

```
     DateTimeOriginal
0   2016:11:11 18:13:05
1   2016:12:18 16:44:59
2   2016:11:12 12:27:25
3   2016:08:20 12:59:02
4   2016:12:17 14:34:29
```

I would like to use these informations to rename the files like : year_month_01 year_month_02  with the last value starting to 0 for each new month.
But i don't arrive to generate these value (ValueToGenerate), after having split the col and sorted by month can you help ?
The first column is index column.
Thanks a lot

```
    Year    Month   Day     ValueToGenerate
26  2016    08      20        1
23  2016    08      20        2
21  2016    08      20        3
11  2016    09      24        1
10  2016    09      25        2 
19  2016    11      10        1 
24  2016    11      12        2
```

Comment: `year_month_01` what does 01 mean ? the day ?

Comment: 01 is just an unique ID for the end of the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['ValueToGenerate'] = df.groupby(['Year','Month']).cumcount() + 1
```